# Compile Collada DOM (c++) for use in iOS

Tags: c++, objective-c, cmake

I want to use the [Collada DOM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/collada-dom/), which is a c++ library, in my current iOS project. Well, the standard procedure for doing so would be:

1. Use cmake to configure the c++ library.
2. Compile a static library for iOS either via make or xcode.
3. Import the static library to xcode and have fun.

Unfortunately nothing of what I did so far was fun at all. I ran into problems right from the beginning. So here is what I did and how I tried to "solve" my problem.

I installed boost, pkgconfig and readline via homebrew. I then used the cmake gui (3.3.0) to create an xcode project which I planned to build in the next step. Cmake stopped with an error telling me it couldn't find boost. So I set boost paths in the CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include")
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib")
```

This helped and I was able to successfully configure the project. I then opened it up in xcode only to realize that the included architectures are OSX only. I googled around until I stumbled across the [ios.cmake toolchain file](https://code.google.com/p/ios-cmake/) that supposedly allows for cross-compilation to iOS. So I pointed cmake to this toolchain file and tried to configure the project again. But to no avail. This time, cmake complained it wouldn't find the compilers. I had to change lines 30 and 31 in the toolchain file to:

```
# Force the compilers to gcc for iOS
include (CMakeForceCompiler)
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER (/usr/bin/clang GNU)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER (/usr/bin/clang++ GNU)
```

And, in order for cmake to find the SDK, change line 89 to:

```
# Setup iOS developer location
if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT)
    set (CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/${IOS_PLATFORM_LOCATION}/Developer")
```

Now the cmake configuration run through without red errors again. But now the logs told me, there was a lot of stuff cmake couldn't find:

```
Toolchain using default iOS SDK: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk
Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - no
Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - no
Compiling Collada DOM Version 2.4.0
Using cmake version 3.3
installing to /usr/local
compiling with double float precision
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Boost version: 1.58.0
Found the following Boost libraries:
  filesystem
  system
found boost version: 105800
Found ZLIB: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/libz.dylib (found version "1.2.5") 
Found LibXml2: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib (found version "2.9.0") 
libxml2 found
compiling minizip from sources and linking statically
System pcre not found, using local from sources
Found BZip2: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/libbz2.dylib (found version "1.0.6") 
Looking for BZ2_bzCompressInit in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/libbz2.dylib
Looking for BZ2_bzCompressInit in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/libbz2.dylib - not found
Could not find OPTIONAL package Readline
Looking for dirent.h
Looking for dirent.h - not found
Looking for stdint.h
Looking for stdint.h - not found
Looking for inttypes.h
Looking for inttypes.h - not found
Looking for sys/stat.h
Looking for sys/stat.h - not found
Looking for sys/types.h
Looking for sys/types.h - not found
Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - not found
Looking for windows.h
Looking for windows.h - not found
Looking for C++ include type_traits.h
Looking for C++ include type_traits.h - not found
Looking for C++ include bits/type_traits.h
Looking for C++ include bits/type_traits.h - not found
Looking for bcopy
Looking for bcopy - not found
Looking for memmove
Looking for memmove - not found
Looking for strerror
Looking for strerror - not found
Looking for strtoll
Looking for strtoll - not found
Looking for strtoq
Looking for strtoq - not found
Looking for _strtoi64
Looking for _strtoi64 - not found
Looking for stddef.h
Looking for stddef.h - not found
Check size of long long
Check size of long long - failed
Check size of unsigned long long
Check size of unsigned long long - failed
Configuring done
```

When opening the xcode project and trying to build, this time I was presented with 7 errors in the minizip library:

```
Semantic Issue
Use of undeclared identifier 'Dfseeko64'; did you mean 'feesko'?

Semantic Issue
'FILE *(*)(const char *restrict, const char *restrict)' and 'int (*)(FILE*, off_t, int)' are not pointers to compatible types

Semantic Issue 
Use of undeclared identifier 'Dftel64'
```

etc...

It seems like the minizip library doesn't contain the right architectures. But honestly I've got no idea how to proceed from here. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Just for the record, here are the full configuration scripts. CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6.0)
project (collada-dom)
set( CMAKE_ALLOW_LOOSE_LOOP_CONSTRUCTS TRUE )

# fix boost location
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include")
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib")

# Define here the needed parameters
set (COLLADA_DOM_VERSION_MAJOR 2)
set (COLLADA_DOM_VERSION_MINOR 4)
set (COLLADA_DOM_VERSION_PATCH 0)
set (COLLADA_DOM_VERSION ${COLLADA_DOM_VERSION_MAJOR}.${COLLADA_DOM_VERSION_MINOR}.${COLLADA_DOM_VERSION_PATCH})
set (COLLADA_DOM_SOVERSION ${COLLADA_DOM_VERSION_MAJOR}.${COLLADA_DOM_VERSION_MINOR})

message(STATUS "Compiling Collada DOM Version ${COLLADA_DOM_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using cmake version ${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}" )

# http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2.6.html#policy:CMP0002
cmake_policy(SET CMP0002 NEW)
# http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2.6.html#policy:CMP0003
cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)

# Use, i.e. don't skip the full RPATH for the build tree
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)

# When building, don't use the install RPATH already
# (but later on when installing)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)

# The RPATH to be used when installing
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib${LIB_SUFFIX}")

# Add the automatically determined parts of the RPATH
# which point to directories outside the build tree to the install RPATH
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

message(STATUS "installing to ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")

##############################################################################
# Custom CMake options
##############################################################################

option(OPT_COLLADA15 "Enable collada 1.5 compilation" ON)
option(OPT_COLLADA14 "Enable collada 1.4 compilation" ON)
option(OPT_COMPILE_VIEWER "Enable collada viewer compilation" OFF)
option(OPT_COMPILE_FX "Enable collada fx compilation" OFF)
option(OPT_COMPILE_RT "Enable collada rt compilation" OFF)
option(OPT_BUILD_PACKAGES "Set to ON to generate CPack configuration files and packaging targets" OFF)
option(OPT_BUILD_PACKAGE_DEFAULT "Set to ON to generate a default openrave package that creates symlinks" ON)
option(OPT_DOUBLE_PRECISION "Use double precision for everything (daeFloat included)" ON)

set(COLLADA_DOM_EXTERNAL_FLAGS)
if( OPT_COLLADA14 )
  set(COLLADA_DOM_EXTERNAL_FLAGS "${COLLADA_DOM_EXTERNAL_FLAGS} -DCOLLADA_DOM_SUPPORT141")
endif()
if( OPT_COLLADA15 )
  set(COLLADA_DOM_EXTERNAL_FLAGS "${COLLADA_DOM_EXTERNAL_FLAGS} -DCOLLADA_DOM_SUPPORT150")
endif()

set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME collada-dom${COLLADA_DOM_SOVERSION})
if(OPT_DOUBLE_PRECISION)
  set(COLLADA_PRECISION "dp")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME "${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME}-dp")
  set(COLLADA_DOM_EXTERNAL_FLAGS "${COLLADA_DOM_EXTERNAL_FLAGS} -DCOLLADA_DOM_DAEFLOAT_IS64") # daeFloat is 64 bit
  message(STATUS "compiling with double float precision")
else()
  set(COLLADA_PRECISION "sp")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME "${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME}-sp")
  message(STATUS "compiling with single float precision")
endif()


if( OPT_COMPILE_VIEWER )
  message(WARNING "compiling collada viewer currently not supported")
endif()
if( OPT_COMPILE_FX )
  message(WARNING "compiling collada fx currently not supported")
endif()
if( OPT_COMPILE_RT )
  message(WARNING "compiling collada rt currently not supported")
endif()

set(PACKAGE_VERSION "0" CACHE STRING "the package-specific version used for uploading the sources")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-modules")
set(COMPONENT_PREFIX "${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME}")
string(TOUPPER ${COMPONENT_PREFIX} COMPONENT_PREFIX_UPPER)
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL ${COMPONENT_PREFIX}-base ${COMPONENT_PREFIX}-dev)

if( MSVC )
  if( MSVC70 OR MSVC71 )
    set(MSVC_PREFIX "vc70")
  elseif( MSVC80 )
    set(MSVC_PREFIX "vc80")
  elseif( MSVC90 )
    set(MSVC_PREFIX "vc90")
  else()
    set(MSVC_PREFIX "vc100")
  endif()
  set(COLLADA_DOM_LIBRARY_SUFFIX "${COLLADA_DOM_SOVERSION}-${COLLADA_PRECISION}-${MSVC_PREFIX}-mt")
else()
  set(COLLADA_DOM_LIBRARY_SUFFIX "${COLLADA_DOM_SOVERSION}-${COLLADA_PRECISION}")
endif()

include(CheckIncludeFile)
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
include(CheckLibraryExists)
include(CheckFunctionExists)
include(CheckCXXSourceCompiles)
#include(CheckCXXSourceRuns)
#include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
include(CheckTypeSize)
find_package(PkgConfig)

if( CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX )
  add_definitions("-fno-strict-aliasing -Wall")
endif()

if( CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX )
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2")# -DNDEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -D_SECURE_SCL=0") # this practically removes all checks making it a very dangerous options to play with
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O2 -g")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -D_DEBUG")
endif()

if( UNIX OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX )
  set(STDC_LIBRARY stdc++)
else()
  set(STDC_LIBRARY)
endif()

if( APPLE OR ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
  # apple doesn't have 64bit versions of file opening functions, so add them
  add_definitions("-Dfopen64=fopen -Dfseeko64=fseeko -Dfseek64=fseek -Dftell64=ftell -Dftello64=ftello")
endif()

set(COLLADA_DOM_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR "include/collada-dom${COLLADA_DOM_SOVERSION}")

set(COLLADA_DOM_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dom/include)
set(COLLADA_DOM_LINK_DIRS "")

if( MSVC )
  # force multi-threaded DLL boost
  set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREAD ON)
  set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
  set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
  set(Boost_CFLAGS "-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB")
endif()

set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.46" "1.45" "1.44" "1.43" "1.42" "1.41" "1.40" "1.39" "1.38" "1.37.0" "1.37" "1.35.0" "1.34.1" "1.34.0" "1.34" "1.33.1" "1.33.0" "1.33")

if( NOT $ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} STREQUAL "" )
  set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR $ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})
endif()
if( NOT $ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} STREQUAL "" )
  set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS $ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})
endif()
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "found boost version: ${Boost_VERSION}")

if( Boost_FOUND )
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(COLLADA_DOM_LINK_DIRS ${COLLADA_DOM_LINK_DIRS} ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
elseif(Boost_VERSION AND NOT "${Boost_VERSION}" STREQUAL "0")
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(COLLADA_DOM_LINK_DIRS ${COLLADA_DOM_LINK_DIRS} ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost libraries!")
endif()

set(COLLADA_DOM_BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS)
foreach(idir ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(COLLADA_DOM_BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS "${COLLADA_DOM_BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS} -I${idir}")
endforeach()

set(COLLADA_DOM_BOOST_LIB_DIRS)
foreach(ldir ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
  set(COLLADA_DOM_BOOST_LIB_DIRS "${COLLADA_DOM_BOOST_LIB_DIRS} -L${ldir}")
endforeach()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  set(EXTRA_COMPILE_FLAGS "${COLLADA_DOM_EXTERNAL_FLAGS} -DCOLLADA_DOM_NAMESPACE -fPIC")
else()
  set(EXTRA_COMPILE_FLAGS "${COLLADA_DOM_EXTERNAL_FLAGS} -DCOLLADA_DOM_NAMESPACE")
endif()

find_package(ZLIB)
if( NOT ZLIB_FOUND )
  message(STATUS "compiling zlib from souces and linking statically")
  # compile from sources
  add_subdirectory(dom/external-libs/zlib-1.2.5)
  set(ZLIB_FOUND 1)
  set(ZLIB_LIBRARIES zlib)
  set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dom/external-libs/zlib-1.2.5)
endif()

find_package(LibXml2)
if( LIBXML2_FOUND )
  include_directories(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR})
  add_definitions(${LIBXML2_DEFINITIONS} -DDOM_INCLUDE_LIBXML)
  message(STATUS "libxml2 found")
else()
  if( MSVC )
    set(LIBXML2_LIBRARY_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dom/external-libs/libxml2-new/lib")
    set(LIBXML2_LIBRARIES "${LIBXML2_LIBRARY_DIRS}/libxml2-${MSVC_PREFIX}-mt.lib")
    set(LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dom/external-libs/libxml2-new/include)
    set(LIBXML2_DEFINITIONS)
    set(LIBXML2_FOUND 1)
    include_directories(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR})
    add_definitions(-DDOM_INCLUDE_LIBXML)
    # have to install the DLLs
    install(DIRECTORY "${LIBXML2_LIBRARY_DIRS}/" DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX} FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*-${MSVC_PREFIX}-*.dll")
  else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find libxml2")
  endif()
endif()

pkg_check_modules(minizip minizip)
if(minizip_FOUND)
  set(MINIZIP_INCLUDE_DIR ${minizip_INCLUDE_DIRS})
else()
  message(STATUS "compiling minizip from sources and linking statically")
  add_subdirectory(dom/external-libs/minizip-1.1)
  set(MINIZIP_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dom/external-libs/minizip-1.1 ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

pkg_check_modules(libpcrecpp libpcrecpp)
if( libpcrecpp_FOUND )
  set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES ${libpcrecpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  check_include_file_cxx(pcrecpp.h HAVE_PCRECPP_H)
  set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES)
  if( NOT HAVE_PCRECPP_H )
    set(libpcrecpp_FOUND 0)
  endif()
endif()

if( NOT libpcrecpp_FOUND )
  message(STATUS "System pcre not found, using local from sources")
  # include the local pcre
  add_subdirectory(dom/external-libs/pcre-8.02)
  set(libpcrecpp_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dom/external-libs/pcre-8.02)
  set(libpcrecpp_LIBRARY_DIRS)
  set(libpcrecpp_LIBRARIES pcrecpp_local)
  set(libpcrecpp_CFLAGS_OTHERS "-DPCRE_STATIC")
  set(libpcrecpp_LDFLAGS_OTHERS)
endif()

# declare minizip/zlib before libxml2! (for some reason the precompiled libxml2 libraries have zlib.h/zconf.h)
include_directories(BEFORE ${MINIZIP_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(BEFORE ${libpcrecpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(COLLADA_DOM_LINK_DIRS ${COLLADA_DOM_LINK_DIRS} ${libpcrecpp_LIBRARY_DIRS})
link_directories(${COLLADA_DOM_LINK_DIRS})

add_subdirectory(dom)

if(UNIX)
  configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/collada-dom.pc.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/collada-dom.pc" @ONLY IMMEDIATE)
  install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/collada-dom.pc DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX}/pkgconfig COMPONENT ${COMPONENT_PREFIX}-dev)
endif()

if( OPT_COLLADA15 )
  if(UNIX)
    configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/collada-dom-150.pc.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/collada-dom-150.pc" @ONLY IMMEDIATE)
    install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/collada-dom-150.pc DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX}/pkgconfig COMPONENT ${COMPONENT_PREFIX}-dev)
  endif()
endif()

if( OPT_COLLADA14 )
  if(UNIX)
    configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/collada-dom-141.pc.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/collada-dom-141.pc" @ONLY IMMEDIATE)
    install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/collada-dom-141.pc DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX}/pkgconfig COMPONENT ${COMPONENT_PREFIX}-dev)
  endif()
endif()

configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/collada_dom-config.cmake.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/collada_dom-config.cmake" @ONLY IMMEDIATE)
configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/collada_dom-config-version.cmake.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/collada_dom-config-version.cmake" @ONLY IMMEDIATE)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/collada_dom-config.cmake" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/collada_dom-config-version.cmake" DESTINATION "lib${LIB_SUFFIX}/cmake/collada_dom-${COLLADA_DOM_SOVERSION}" COMPONENT ${COMPONENT_PREFIX}-dev)

# add make uninstall capability
configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-modules/cmake_uninstall.cmake.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake" IMMEDIATE @ONLY)

add_custom_target(uninstall "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake")

if(CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND AND UNIX AND OPT_BUILD_PACKAGES)
  # Packing information
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME collada-dom${COLLADA_DOM_SOVERSION})
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "" CACHE STRING "Package maintainer and PGP signer.")
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "http://sourceforge.net/projects/collada-dom")
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DISPLAY_NAME "collada-dom ${COLLADA_DOM_VERSION}")
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY " - COLLADA")
  if( OPT_DOUBLE_PRECISION )
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "${CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY} using double precision")
  else()
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "${CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY} using single precision")
  endif()
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION ${COLLADA_DOM_VERSION}.${PACKAGE_VERSION})
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR ${COLLADA_DOM_VERSION_MAJOR})
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR ${COLLADA_DOM_VERSION_MINOR})
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH ${COLLADA_DOM_VERSION_PATCH})
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "collada-dom${COLLADA_DOM_SOVERSION}")
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/description)
  set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dom/license.txt)

  set(CPACK_COMPONENT_${COMPONENT_PREFIX_UPPER}-BASE_DISPLAY_NAME "core libraries")
  set(CPACK_COMPONENT_${COMPONENT_PREFIX_UPPER}-DEV_DISPLAY_NAME "C++ headers and build tools")
  set(CPACK_COMPONENT_${COMPONENT_PREFIX_UPPER}-DEV_DEPENDS ${COMPONENT_PREFIX}-base)

  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_BUILD_DEPENDS debhelper cmake libxml2-dev libboost-dev zlib1g-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-system-dev libpcre3-dev pkg-config)

  # debian
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_PRIORITY optional)
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SECTION libs)
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS ${CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL})
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SUGGESTS)
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_CMAKE_OPTIONS "-DOPT_DOUBLE_PRECISION=${OPT_DOUBLE_PRECISION} -DOPT_BUILD_PACKAGE_DEFAULT=${OPT_BUILD_PACKAGE_DEFAULT}")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_REMOVE_SOURCE_FILES viewer fx rt Makefile.linux Makefile dom/codeGen dom/Makefile dom/external-libs/boost dom/external-libs/libxml2 dom/external-libs/minizip dom/external-libs/pcre dom/external-libs/pcre-8.02 dom/external-libs/zlib-1.2.5 dom/test dom/release dom/projects dom/make)
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SOURCE_COPY svn export --force)
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_CHANGELOG)
  execute_process(COMMAND lsb_release -is
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE _lsb_distribution OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    RESULT_VARIABLE _lsb_release_failed)
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_DISTRIBUTION_NAME ${_lsb_distribution} CACHE STRING "Name of the distrubiton")
  string(TOLOWER ${CPACK_DEBIAN_DISTRIBUTION_NAME} CPACK_DEBIAN_DISTRIBUTION_NAME)
  if( ${CPACK_DEBIAN_DISTRIBUTION_NAME} STREQUAL "ubuntu" )
    set(CPACK_DEBIAN_DISTRIBUTION_RELEASES lucid maverick natty oneiric precise CACHE STRING "Release code-names of the distrubiton release")
  endif()
  set(CPACK_COMPONENT_COLLADA-DOM_DEPENDS ${CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL})

  if( OPT_BUILD_PACKAGE_DEFAULT )
    set(CPACK_COMPONENT_COLLADA-DOM-DEV_RECOMMENDS ${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME}-dev)
    set(CPACK_COMPONENT_COLLADA-DOM-DEV_DISPLAY_NAME ${CPACK_COMPONENT_${COMPONENT_PREFIX_UPPER}-DEV_DISPLAY_NAME})
    set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL ${CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL} collada-dom-dev)
  endif()

  set(DPUT_HOST "" CACHE STRING "PPA repository to upload the debian sources")
  include(CPack)
  include(DebSourcePPA)
endif()
```

iOS.cmake:

```
# This file is based off of the Platform/Darwin.cmake and Platform/UnixPaths.cmake
# files which are included with CMake 2.8.4
# It has been altered for iOS development

# Options:
#
# IOS_PLATFORM = OS (default) or SIMULATOR
#   This decides if SDKS will be selected from the iPhoneOS.platform or iPhoneSimulator.platform folders
#   OS - the default, used to build for iPhone and iPad physical devices, which have an arm arch.
#   SIMULATOR - used to build for the Simulator platforms, which have an x86 arch.
#
# CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT = automatic(default) or /path/to/platform/Developer folder
#   By default this location is automatcially chosen based on the IOS_PLATFORM value above.
#   If set manually, it will override the default location and force the user of a particular Developer Platform
#
# CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT = automatic(default) or /path/to/platform/Developer/SDKs/SDK folder
#   By default this location is automatcially chosen based on the CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT value.
#   In this case it will always be the most up-to-date SDK found in the CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT path.
#   If set manually, this will force the use of a specific SDK version

# Standard settings
set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Darwin)
set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1 )
set (UNIX True)
set (APPLE True)
set (IOS True)

# Force the compilers to gcc for iOS
include (CMakeForceCompiler)
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER (/usr/bin/clang GNU)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER (/usr/bin/clang++ GNU)

# Skip the platform compiler checks for cross compiling
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
set (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)

# All iOS/Darwin specific settings - some may be redundant
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "lib")
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX ".dylib")
set (CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_PREFIX "lib")
set (CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_SUFFIX ".so")
set (CMAKE_MODULE_EXISTS 1)
set (CMAKE_DL_LIBS "")

set (CMAKE_C_OSX_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION_FLAG "-compatibility_version ")
set (CMAKE_C_OSX_CURRENT_VERSION_FLAG "-current_version ")
set (CMAKE_CXX_OSX_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION_FLAG "${CMAKE_C_OSX_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION_FLAG}")
set (CMAKE_CXX_OSX_CURRENT_VERSION_FLAG "${CMAKE_C_OSX_CURRENT_VERSION_FLAG}")

# Hidden visibilty is required for cxx on iOS 
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "")
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-headerpad_max_install_names -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden")

set (CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-search_paths_first ${CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS}")
set (CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-search_paths_first ${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS}")

set (CMAKE_PLATFORM_HAS_INSTALLNAME 1)
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CREATE_C_FLAGS "-dynamiclib -headerpad_max_install_names")
set (CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_CREATE_C_FLAGS "-bundle -headerpad_max_install_names")
set (CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_LOADER_C_FLAG "-Wl,-bundle_loader,")
set (CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_LOADER_CXX_FLAG "-Wl,-bundle_loader,")
set (CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".dylib" ".so" ".a")

# hack: if a new cmake (which uses CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL) runs on an old build tree
# (where install_name_tool was hardcoded) and where CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL isn't in the cache
# and still cmake didn't fail in CMakeFindBinUtils.cmake (because it isn't rerun)
# hardcode CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL here to install_name_tool, so it behaves as it did before, Alex
if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL)
    find_program(CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL install_name_tool)
endif (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL)

# Setup iOS platform
if (NOT DEFINED IOS_PLATFORM)
    set (IOS_PLATFORM "OS")
endif (NOT DEFINED IOS_PLATFORM)
set (IOS_PLATFORM ${IOS_PLATFORM} CACHE STRING "Type of iOS Platform")

# Check the platform selection and setup for developer root
if (${IOS_PLATFORM} STREQUAL "OS")
    set (IOS_PLATFORM_LOCATION "iPhoneOS.platform")
elseif (${IOS_PLATFORM} STREQUAL "SIMULATOR")
    set (IOS_PLATFORM_LOCATION "iPhoneSimulator.platform")
else (${IOS_PLATFORM} STREQUAL "OS")
    message (FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported IOS_PLATFORM value selected. Please choose OS or SIMULATOR")
endif (${IOS_PLATFORM} STREQUAL "OS")

# Setup iOS developer location
if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT)
    set (CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/${IOS_PLATFORM_LOCATION}/Developer")
endif (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT)
set (CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT ${CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT} CACHE PATH "Location of iOS Platform")

# Find and use the most recent iOS sdk 
if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT)
    file (GLOB _CMAKE_IOS_SDKS "${CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT}/SDKs/*")
    if (_CMAKE_IOS_SDKS) 
        list (SORT _CMAKE_IOS_SDKS)
        list (REVERSE _CMAKE_IOS_SDKS)
        list (GET _CMAKE_IOS_SDKS 0 CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT)
    else (_CMAKE_IOS_SDKS)
        message (FATAL_ERROR "No iOS SDK's found in default seach path ${CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT}. Manually set CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT or install the iOS SDK.")
    endif (_CMAKE_IOS_SDKS)
    message (STATUS "Toolchain using default iOS SDK: ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT}")
endif (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT)
set (CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT} CACHE PATH "Location of the selected iOS SDK")

# Set the sysroot default to the most recent SDK
set (CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT} CACHE PATH "Sysroot used for iOS support")

# set the architecture for iOS - using ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT sets armv6,armv7 and appears to be XCode's standard. 
# The other value that works is ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS but that sets armv7 only
set (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)" CACHE string  "Build architecture for iOS")

# Set the find root to the iOS developer roots and to user defined paths
set (CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT} ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT} ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} CACHE string  "iOS find search path root")

# default to searching for frameworks first
set (CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK FIRST)

# set up the default search directories for frameworks
set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH
    ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT}/System/Library/Frameworks
    ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT}/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks
    ${CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT}/Developer/Library/Frameworks
)

# only search the iOS sdks, not the remainder of the host filesystem
set (CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM ONLY)
set (CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set (CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Answer (score 0):

The iOS toolchain currently doesn't support TRY_COMPILE, which is used by CheckIncludeFiles.cmake. The toolchain is currently set to skip TRY_COMPILE by using:

```
# Skip the platform compiler checks for cross compiling
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
set (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
```

To fix `try_compile`, you'll need to comment out those lines and add this to the top of the IOS.cmake toolchain file.

```
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example)
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_BUNDLE YES)
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer")
```